# Recycle all file except those in list using batch file on windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I want to run my program ***recycle.exe*** on all files inside a directory named ***appname*** except those files that are present in the list ***exclude***. I run the following batch file but I get errors. Can anybody correct this code please?

```
@echo off

set exclude=Uploads Web.config

set appname=Publish

set found=DUMMY

for /F "tokens=*" %%I in ('dir /b %appname%') do (



        echo %found%

        set found=NO

        for %%J in (%exclude%) do (
            if %%I == %%J (set found=YES )

            echo %%I %%J %found%
        )

        if %found%==YES recycle.exe %%I

        )


pause
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to over complicate it. Try this.

```
@echo off
set "exclude=upload web.config"
set "directory=c:\some path\publish"
for %%f in (%directory%) do (
    if not /I "%exclude%" == "%%f" echo recycle.exe "%%f"
)
```

I am on my phone so cannot test it. But it should only echo the file names except for "Uploads Web.config"

Once you confirm it will do what intended to do, remove `echo` from the last line.